# Динамический роутинг в Angular

Tags: angular

Настроил в своем проекте роутинг

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a routerLink="">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>   
            <a routerLink="/about">О сайте</a>
        </li>       
        <li>   
            <a routerLink="/no-found">Такой страницы нет</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Все работает, но я не могу понять как можно сделать роутинг для динамического меню.
Например, у меня меню создается из массива, во время загрузки приложения.
Как в этом случае назначить каждому элементу меню свой маршрут?
Попробовал вот так:

```
*ngFor="let menu of menus, let index = index"
<a
(click)="setRefPage(menu.name)"
[routerLink]="pageName"
>{{menu.name}}</a>
```

Не работает, т.к. сначала идет присвоение атрибута routerLink, а потом уже вызвается функция setRefPage, которая присваивает переменной pageName новый путь.

Comment: `[routerLink]="[menu.name]"` ?

Comment: Теоретически можно добавить в этот объект переменную page и тогда будет
[routerLink]="[menu.page]"
Я просто хотел узнать на сколько это правильно. Как то мало информации по роутингу в Angular

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как у Вас роуты организованы. Информации более чем достаточно. 
А так-то, добавьте в массив каждому пункту page и используйте menu.page, вполне нормальное решение